# Can't import tkinter to python file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I installed and imported tkinter into my .py file named tkinter.py. It keeps showing the error "module object is not callable".

My code goes like this:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter()
window.title = ("My First Tkinter Program")
window.geometry = ("1200x660")


# Create Main Frame
my_frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

# Create Scroll Bar
text_scroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side="RIGHT", fill="Y")


# Create Text Box
my_text = tkinter.Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 20), selectbackground="yellow", selectforeground="#000", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)

# Configure the Scroll Bar
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)


window.mainloop()
```

Where did I go wrong??

Comment: `window = tkinter()` must be `window = tkinter.Tk()`. You can't call the module `tkinter` as a function.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.12.0rc3, Windows 10.

> It keeps showing the error "module object is not callable".

Using same script.

You must use `tkinter` then do `tkinter.` prefix for widgets. Same as you do in `pack()`.

Snippet same same script as your:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title = ("My First Tkinter Program")
window.geometry = ("1200x660")


# Create Main Frame
my_frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

# Create Scroll Bar
text_scroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)


# Create Text Box
my_text = tkinter.Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 20), selectbackground="yellow", selectforeground="#000", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)

# Configure the Scroll Bar
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)


window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

the error because of the naming, you named your Python script tkinter.py and the instance of the tkinter module with window = tkinter(), it's treating your script as the tkinter module itself.
try to rename things for example:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()  # Create a tkinter window instance
window.title("My First Tkinter Program")
window.geometry("1200x660")

# Create Main Frame
my_frame = tk.Frame(window)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

# Create Scroll Bar
text_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side="RIGHT", fill="Y")

# Create Text Box
my_text = tk.Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 20), selectbackground="yellow", selectforeground="#000", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)

# Configure the Scroll Bar
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: "module object is not callable" is not caused by the naming of the module. OP is doing `window = tkinter()`.

Comment: okay , that what i mean see in the code block
line 1:
window = tk.Tk()  # Create a tkinter window instance